# Missing resnet_v1_50.ckpt and DeepLabCut failed to train the network (Deep-learning)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6

I installed Deep Lab Cut and tried to run `deeplabcut.train_network(config_path,shuffle=1)`.

But,I got the following message

`ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeplabcut/pose_estimation_tensorflow/models/pretrained/resnet_v1_50.ckpt`

I have searched "resnet_v1_50.ckpt", but the file don't exist on my computer.

Fortunately, I have found the solution:   https://github.com/AlexEMG/DeepLabCut/blob/master/examples/Docker_TrainNetwork_VideoAnalysis.ipynb

According to the section "A couple tips for possible troubleshooting (1)" of this page, if I run `sudo download.sh` and `sudo chown yourusername:yourusername resnet_v1_50.ckpt`, this problem will be solved.

However, `download.sh` can't run on the Ubuntu terminal and I can't solve this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: just check the path to the "resnet_v1_50.ckpt" in the code

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked the path. I found out the file "download.sh" on the path `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeplabcut/pose_estimation_tensorflow/models/pretrained/`. Then I run this file and other commands `mv resnet_v1_50.ckpt /home/user/anaconda3/envs/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/deeplabcut/pose_estimation_tensorflow/models/pretrained/resnet_v1_50.ckpt`, the error was resolved.